# Syntax error with SQL queries with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a problem using backslashes with ' in a query launched in python.
This is the query:

```
c.execute("SELECT Num FROM Table WHERE cie = 'TAB_' AND tablecode = 'IDL\DOC\'TAB_'\'{G}'\'FV'\'          ' ' ".format(G=date.today().year))
```

the problem is that even if I do something like this :

```
c.execute("SELECT Num FROM Table WHERE cie = 'TAB_' AND tablecode = 'IDL\\DOC\\'TAB_'\\'{G}'\\'FV'\\'          ' ' ".format(G=date.today().year))
```

it gives me the same error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'TAB_'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

My field in sql contains values like this : VALUE1\VALUE2'VALUE3'\'    '
So I have to use backslashes
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post some sample data so that someone can replicate the SQL query?
There is an issue with your apostrophes in the tablecode section.

Comment: You have unescaped single quotes in your literal.

Comment: **Parameterize your query**, this fixes your problem and also deals with your injection vulnerability. If you *really* cannot parameterize then escape the quote by doubling it

Comment: [Why should you use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: I parameterized my query but it still doesn't work @Charlieface

Comment: So your code is now `c.execute("SELECT Num FROM Table WHERE cie = 'TAB_' AND tablecode = ?", ( "IDL\DOC\'TAB_'\'{G}'\'FV'\'          ".format(date.today().year), ))` right?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work, it only works writing it in this way : 

    c.execute("SELECT Num FROM table WHERE cie = 'TAB_' AND tablecode = 'IDL\DOC\\''TAB_''\\''{G}''\\''FV''\\''          '' '  ".format(G=date.today().year)).fetchone()[0]

@Charlieface

Comment: You are going to have to show the exact code you have currently, that should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, so basically there's no result with that condition, meaning that it's written wrongly